# Tag edit history blank on app

Tags: bug, ios-app, tag-wiki, revisions-list

I tried following [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/119739/revisions) to the revision history of a tag, but the page was blank. It is possible to pull to refresh though:

[image]

This should either show the revision history (like a regular post) or open the in-app web browser. This is how it (correctly) looks in a browser:

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)